# Shipping costs based on weight and cart subtotal

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

So far I have the shipping costs based on the total weight of the cart.
Orders with a total weight below 100 pay 1.95 and above 5.95.

Now what I'm trying to achieve is to adjust these shipping costs based on the cart subtotal. So when the total weight is below 100 AND the subtotal is above 20 shipping is free. When the total weight is equal to or above 100 AND the subtotal is above 20 shipping is 1.95.

I am using Magento CE 1.9. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Suggest try Amasty table rates extension.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: when the total weight is below 100 AND the subtotal is above 20 shipping is free

Solution: You can add shopping cart price rule for this, from `Admin Panel` -> `Promotions` -> `Shopping Cart Price Rules`
[image: Conditions]

- In conditions, add subtotal > 20 AND weight < 100

[image: Actions]

- In Actions, enable free shipping for above rule

For next part, When the total weight is equal to or above 100 AND the subtotal is above 20 shipping is 1.95

- Define your default shipping rate as 1.95